# Generate single complex JSON object from PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with the following tables:

`Building`

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Building 1 | 1st Building Description |
| 2 | Building 2 | 2nd Building Description |
| 3 | Building 3 | 3rd Building Description |

`Floor`

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | BUILDING_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Floor 1.1 | Floor Description 1.1 | 1 |
| 2 | Floor 1.2 | Floor Description 1.2 | 1 |
| 3 | Floor 2.1 | Floor Description 2.1 | 2 |
| 4 | Floor 2.2 | Floor Description 2.2 | 2 |
| 5 | Floor 3.1 | Floor Description 3.1 | 3 |

`Room`

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | FLOOR_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room 1.1.1 | Room Description 1.1.1 | 1 |
| 2 | Room 1.1.2 | Room Description 1.1.2 | 1 |
| 3 | Room 1.2.1 | Room Description 1.2.1 | 2 |
| 4 | Room 1.2.2 | Room Description 1.2.2 | 2 |
| 5 | Room 3.1.1 | Room Description 2.1.1 | 5 |

**The code** for generating the above structure can be found in this **SQL Fiddle**, [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1751).

I want to generate a single JSON object with a single query, with the following structure:

```
{
  "Building 1": {
    "details": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Building 1",
      "description": "1st Building Description"
    },
    "floors": {
      "Floor 1.1": {
        "details": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Floor 1.1",
          "description": "Floor Description 1.1"
        },
        "rooms": {
          "Room 1.1.1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Room 1.1.1",
            "description": "Room Description 1.1.1"
          },
          "Room 1.1.2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Room 1.1.2",
            "description": "Room Description 1.1.2"
          }
        }
      },
      "Floor 1.2": {
        "details": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Floor 1.2",
          "description": "Floor Description 1.2"
        },
        "rooms": {
          "Room 1.2.1": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Room 1.2.1",
            "description": "Room Description 1.2.1"
          },
          "Room 1.1.2": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Room 1.2.2",
            "description": "Room Description 1.2.2"
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  
  
  "Building 2": {
    "details": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Building 2",
      "description": "2nd Building Description"
    },
    "floors": {
      "Floor 2.1": {
        "details": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Floor 2.1",
          "description": "Floor Description 2.1"
        },
        "rooms": {
        }
      },
      "Floor 2.2": {
        "details": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Floor 2.2",
          "description": "Floor Description 2.2"
        },
        "rooms": {
        }
      },
    }
  },
  
    
  
  "Building 3": {
    "details": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Building 3",
      "description": "3rd Building Description"
    },
    "floors": {
      "Floor 3.1": {
        "details": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Floor 3.1",
          "description": "Floor Description 3.1"
        },
        "rooms": {
          "Room 3.1.1": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Room 3.1.1",
            "description": "Room Description 3.1.1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

To explain the above structure:

1. A single object output is needed
2. The keys are always represented by the name of the objects
3. All the fields are contained in a `details` object
4. All the children objects are flattened inside another object in a similar way

Unfortunately, I can only use `json_build_object` because the above structure cannot be altered since it was already defined.

Thank you!

Comment: could you post the script to create table and add datas as we can try to help you ?

Comment: @Philippe it is contained in the SQL fiddle. Can be found here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her you can have an example of what you can do. You will have to correct and complete this script, but I think it can do the job

```
select json_build_object(b.name,json_build_object('details',row_to_json(b),
                        'floors',json_build_object('details',(select json_agg(row_to_json(f))->0 from (select * from floors f where f.building_id = b.id) f)))) 
from buildings b
```